# How to display another form when row is selected in DataGrid?

Tags: .net, winforms, datagrid

I made a database and able to show records in the Winforms `DataGridView`. But I don't know the "key term" or how to explain in order to search it in google on how I want it to display. I want it to work so that once I click on the row value in the grid (example : Room 102 - Section Red) , another form will open?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: On grid event [learn from the link above], do `var f = new MyForm(); f.Show();` - this is all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to open a form on click on datagridview just use the event "**CellContentClick**" and in it just write which form you want to open like

```
Form1 f = new Form1();
f.show();
```